# ADAL: sharing access token between apps on iOS

Tags: ios, adal

Is it possible to share an ADAL access and refresh token with two or more apps on iOS? I've seen a post on Android about this, but not sure if it is possible on iOS.

My guess is that it is shared via a shared pasteboard, but that would require the apps to be signed by the same teamID. To do this, would I just need to set the same userID, or is something else required?

Answer (score 2):

You can share tokens between apps by the same developer.  So, if the user has installed two apps developed by you and they log in using the first, then the second app can access that token.  An app by another developer cannot access the token from your app and so the user will be prompted to log in again.

The tokens are shared through a keychain group.  The instructions are on the [ADALiOS github page](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) but in summary are:

- Click on your project in the Navigator pane in Xcode.
- Click on your application target and then the "Capabilities" tab.
- Scroll down to "Keychain Sharing" and flip the switch on.
- Add `com.microsoft.adalcache` to the keychain sharing list.